# Decision based on a comparison between a sum and a value

Tags: probability, contest-math, combinations

The board of a company needs to make a decision and has two options:

1. Option $1$: following the advice of $1$ advisor. His accuracy is $p
       \in (0,1)$
2. Option $2$: following the advice of $2n$ advisors and an unbiased coin. The
   accuracy of the $2n$ advisors is $p \in (0,1)$, the accuracy of the coin is $0.5$.

Which option the board should use, in function of $p$ and $n$?

### **Problem**

Does there exist a solution that does not require much computation and works for all $n$?

---

### My thoughts

Let $P$ denote the probability of making good decision based on the option $2$. We have
$$\begin{align}
P &= \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}( \ge n \text{ adv make good decision})+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}( \ge (n+1) \text{ adv make good decision} )\\
&=\mathbb{P}( \ge n \text{ adv make good decision}) -\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}( \text{exactly } n \text{ adv make good decision}) \tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\left({2n \choose k} p^{k}(1-p)^{2n-k}\right)-\frac{1}{2}{2n \choose n}(p(1-p))^n \tag{2}\\
\end{align}$$

My solution that ***works only for $n$ large*** is as follows.

> We observe that the decision of every advisor follows the Bernoulli
> distribution $\mathcal{B}(p)$, so the sum of $2n$ decison follows the
> binominal distribution $\mathcal{B}(2n,p)$.
>
> For $n$ large, according to the central limit theorem, this sum
> follows the normal distribution. Then the first probability of $(1)$
> can be approximated by $$\mathbb{P}( \ge n \text{ adv make good decision}) \approx \mathbb{P} \left(\mathcal{N}(p,p(1-p) \ge \frac{1}{2}\right) = \Phi \left(\frac{p-\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}} 
>  \right)$$
> The second probability of $(1)$ tends to $0$ for $n\to
>  +\infty$. Finally $$P \approx \Phi \left(\frac{p-\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}  \right)$$ It suffices then
> to choose the larger value between $p$ and $\Phi
>  \left(\frac{p-\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}  \right)$. We choose option
> $1$ if $p<\frac{1}{2}$ and option $2$ if $p>\frac{1}{2}$

However, this solution works only for $n$ large.

I think we don't need to compute $P$, just need to compare the value of $P$ and $p$ and we could use the formula

$${n \choose i} = {n-1 \choose i}+{n-1 \choose i-1}$$
to transform $(2)$.